# Determine directory level of file calling function

Tags: javascript

If there is a function in an iframe,  that loads a file, that file tries to load from the "base href" of the iframe that calls the function.

```
function load_it(){
    top.iframe_1.location='sub_1/file_1.php'
}
```

The above will work only if called from the top page.
If called from `/sub_1/` it tries to load `/sub_1/sub_1/file_1.php`
If called from `/sub_1/sub_2/` it tries to load `/sub_1/sub_2/sub_1/file_1.php`

So I need to prefix '', '../' or '../../' depending on the depth of the calling page.

ie: `../../sub_1/file_1.php`

How can I determine the sub directory level that is needed, within the `load_it` function?

Comment: Can't you just specify an absolute path instead? I.e. `'/sub_1/file_1.php'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute path instead:

```
'/sub_1/file_1.php'
```